# Left Outer Join not returning all rows when resulting value is based existance of match in primary table

Tags: sql, join, isnull

`LEFT JOIN` is not returning all rows in the results. The results are based on the existence of the corresponding value in the primary table.  For example, the `Break` (primary) and `Event` (Secondary) tables.  If the lookup value exists in both, then return the value from the `Event` table.  If the value only exists in the `Break` table, then return the `Break` value. However, if necessary, when `Event` value does not exist, returning the `Break` value with the `Event` value set to zero/NULL would also be acceptable. I scaled down the query to just this portion that I'm having difficulties with as I've researched extensively and can't get this to return accurate results.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ISNULL (e.breaktime, b.breaktime)
FROM
    Break b
LEFT JOIN  Event e (nolock)
    ON  e.breakdate = b.breakdate 
    and e.breaktime = b.breaktime
WHERE
    b.breaktime between 18000 and 86400
GROUP BY b.breaktime, e.breaktime
ORDER BY b.breaktime
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the condition to `JOIN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(e.breaktime, b.breaktime) AS breaktime
  FROM Break b
       LEFT JOIN Event e (NOLOCK)
    ON e.breakdate = b.breakdate 
   AND e.breaktime = b.breaktime
   AND b.breaktime BETWEEN 18000 AND 86400
 GROUP BY b.breaktime, e.breaktime 
 ORDER BY breaktime
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, I've narrowed it down to the link in breaktime.  As soon as I remove the e.breaktime = b.breaktime, then it works correctly and all rows are returned. However, they are completely out of order since the link in breaktimes is necessary for accurate results.  I've linked every column the tables have in common but the breaktime is they key to making it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is you specified the left table as "Event". I think you want to make the statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL (e.breaktime, b.breaktime) 
FROM Break b 
LEFT JOIN Event e (nolock) 
ON 
     b.breakdate = e.breakdate
     and b.breaktime = e.breaktime
WHERE 
     b.breaktime between 18000 and 86400 
GROUP BY b.breaktime, e.breaktime
ORDER BY b.breaktime
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, I've narrowed it down to the link in breaktime.  As soon as I remove the e.breaktime = b.breaktime, then it works correctly and all rows are returned. However, they are completely out of order since the link in breaktimes is necessary for accurate results.  I've linked every column the tables have in common but the breaktime is they key to making it work.